# Exception thrown when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, exception, sqlparameter

```
    private async Task<long> InsertCustomerRecord(CreateCustomerModel model)
    {

        Int64 phoneNumber = 0;
        var isParsed = Int64.TryParse(model.PhoneNumber, out phoneNumber);
        if (!isParsed)
            phoneNumber = 0;
        var USPSAddressValidatedId = (int)model.USPSAddressValidated;
        try
        {
            IDataParameter[] parameters = new IDataParameter[]
            {
            new SqlParameter("@FirstName", model.FirstName.ToUpper()),
            new SqlParameter("@LastName", model.LastName.ToUpper()),
            //new SqlParameter("@MiddleInitial", model.MiddleInitial),
            new SqlParameter("@AddressLine1",model.AddressLine1.ToUpper() ?? ""),
            new SqlParameter("@AddressLine2",model.AddressLine2.ToUpper() ?? ""),
            new SqlParameter("@City",model.City.ToUpper()),
            new SqlParameter("@State",model.State.ToUpper()),
            new SqlParameter("@CountyCode",model.CountyCode.ToUpper()),
            new SqlParameter("@ZipCode",model.ZipCode),
            new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth",model.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString()),
            new SqlParameter("@Phone",phoneNumber),
            new SqlParameter("@Email",model.EmailAddress.ToUpper()??""),
            new SqlParameter("@PersonalRepresentative",model.CustomerClass.ToUpper()),
            new SqlParameter("@ExpiryDate", model.ExpirationDate),
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerClass", model.Customer_Class),
            new SqlParameter("@USPSAddressValidated",USPSAddressValidatedId ),
            new SqlParameter("@ImportFromLegacySystem", model.ImportFromLegacySystem)
            };
        
            return await InsertUpdateProcedure("RF_InsertCustomerCard", parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

The exception thrown is

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
```

Comment: On which line? Code like this is suspicious: `model.EmailAddress.ToUpper()??""` - if EmailAddress is a string, it might be null, but `ToUpper()` will not return null if called on a non-null instance so you wouldn't coalesce it.. If you know EmailAddress could be null then calling `.ToUpper()` on it would result in a crash; the code should look like `model.EmailAddress?.ToUpper()??""` - the `?.` will not call `ToUpper` on a null emailaddress - it will just short cut straight to null, and then `??` *would* make sense

Comment: ListDictionaryInternal isn't even in the code snippet so we can't really tell what's wrong.

Comment: Can you include more information/scope on this issue?

Comment: @AAP the entire method is posted.

Comment: `.ToUpper()` cannot return `null`, so obviously `x.ToUpper() ?? ""` is wrong.

Comment: Exceptions come with line numbers and a stack.  You have a lot of code there, showing that information would help a lot.  The way to figure this out is break just before this code is executed and check which data is null

Comment: You probably want use **null propagation** `?` in combination with **null-coalescing** `??`  e.g. `model.SomeProperty?.ToUpper() ?? ""`. *UPD*: late seen my comment duplicates @Caius Jard comment.

Comment: "Exception is thrown when it _should_ be" FTFY

Comment: THanks everyone!. I can't believe I was that dumb! I missed it. Please put it as the answer so I can give you credit and it may help others @CaiusJard

Comment: Review note: The first 4 lines of this method can be reduced to 1 line: `Int64.TryParse(model.PhoneNumber, out Int64 phoneNumber);`

Comment: Another review note: calling `new SqlParameter(paramName, value)` is (depending on what you do with `parameters `, I suspect assign it to a SqlParameterCollection) highly likely to be the effective equivalent of calling `command.Parameters.AddWithValue`, and [use of AddWithValue is discouraged for SQLServer queries](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something that you suspect might be null:

```
model.EmailAddress
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   this might be null
```

You need to use the null propagating operator on it:

```
model.EmailAddress?.ToUpper() ?? ""
                  ^^
```

This means if it is `null`, then evaluation of the chain of operations will cease at the point that `.EmailAddress` returns `null`, and the sub-expression (`model.EmailAddress?.ToUpper()`) will resolve to `null`. It will then be picked up by the null coalescing operator `??` and turned into whatever you've put on the right hand side of the operator. If it's a constant, like `""` then the whole expression is guaranteed to not be null

You can use these operators multiple times, on property and method return values:

```
thing.Prop?.Method() ?? thing.OtherProp?.OtherMethod()?.AnotherProp ?? "Constant"
```

There is also a null tolerant indexer if collections might be null:

```
//in case the collection is null, or the thing at index 0 is null, or its Property is null...
thing.Collection?[0]?.Property?.Something() ...
                ^^
```